# R terra: cannot update due to 00LOCK file, cant find the lock file

Tags: r, installation, package, terra

I am trying to update the `terra` package in R-4.2.2 and i'm running into the following issue;

```
Warning message:
In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\R\win-library\4.2\00LOCK\terra\libs\x64\terra.dll 
to C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\R\win-library\4.2\terra\libs\x64\terra.dll: Permission denied
```

This has tried with `install.packages("terra")`, `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`
and `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev', INSTALL_opts = '--no-lock')` - to the same result

As per many suggestions, I have gone looking for the 00LOCK file to delete it and try again, but it doesn't exist anywhere I can find it.

The root of my issue is that `dismo` requires `raster` v3.5.21, and updating `raster` so it complies calls on the `terra` download, which errors.

`‘package ‘raster’ 3.5.15 is loaded, but >= 3.5.21 is required by ‘dismo’’`

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close R (and R-Studio), and delete this folder:

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\R\win-library\4.2\terra
```

And, if either exists, also remove these folders.

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\R\win-library\4.2\00LOCK-terra
C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\R\win-library\4.2\00LOCK
```

Then open R and install "terra"

Comment: ok thank you, that seemed to work (the deleting of terra, the others didn't exist)